# In C++, What does "access" mean in the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

3.10/10 says:

> If a program attempts to **access** the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undeﬁned:

However, the term "access" is not defined anywhere. In this context does it mean *read*,  or *read or modify* ?

---

In the C standard it is unambiguously defined as *read or modify*.  However in C++11 it seems to be used with different meanings at different times, for example:

1.9/8:

> Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

Clearly this is meant to be *read or modify*, however in many other places such as 1.10/24:

> - access or modify a volatile object, or

it is used as if it only means *read*.

Comment: You could shorten the title to: "In C++, what does 'access' mean?" This is a great question. (Of course, regarding the strict aliasing rule specifically, the intent is surely "read or modify", similar to C.)

Comment: @Nemo Agree, although I am most interested in this particular case.  That could be a separate question perhaps.

Comment: Well, regardless of their intent in this section, they have certainly not stated it clearly, so I would say you have definitely found a bug in the spec.

Comment: The standard is notoriously bad at this sort of thing. Even a rabid language lawyer like myself avoids such questions like the plague. You're on your own ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit heh. Strict aliasing problems are horrible enough to unwind without this ambiguity thrown into the mix. I'd always assumed it should be as in C; but I've been reading a few other answers on strict aliasing (particularly relating to combining with placement new) and they all tacitly rely on *access* only meaning *read*, so I was hoping to clear this up before commenting/posting further on strict aliasing

Comment: Placement new is a little odd - it reuses the storage, which ends the lifetime of the object that's been there before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must mean both read and write, or the rule wouldn't mean much. Consider the example from http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html:

```
float *P;
void zero_array() {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
       P[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

The example code above can be optimized into a `memset` only if the compiler can assume that none of `P[i]` aliases `P`. But consider a world in which only *reading* from an disallowed glvalue is UB, then the above code would not invoke UB even if `P[i]` aliases `P` for some `i` - e.g., if someone did `P = (float *) &P;`, because all *reads* of `P` are perfectly legal - they all use the lvalue expression `P`.

---

**Edit**: [CWG issue 1531](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1531) is directly on point. The issue was moved to DR (defect report) status in April 2013, but the resolution, for whatever reason, wasn't applied to the working paper.

Comment: Great example (as is your example in the other comment)

Comment: I would see no difficulty with the Standard specifying that cross-type reads of a PODS yield potentially-Indeterminate Value, and cross-type writes of a PODS set it to potentially-Intermediate Value, at least if the Standard were clearer about what can and cannot happen when working with Intermediate Values of types which have no natural trap representations (a point the Standard should address anyway, IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim to be a language lawyer. However...

I would interpret the phrase "access the stored value of an object" as "**read** the stored value of an object".

That interpretation makes more sense given the previous paragraph, which talks about modifying an object.

> 9 If an expression can be used to modify the object to which it refers, the expression is called modifiable. A program that attempts to modify an object through a nonmodifiable lvalue or rvalue expression is ill-formed.

Comment: By this reading, stuff like `int a = 0; *((short *) &a) = 100; std::cout << a;` doesn't break strict aliasing. That makes little sense.

Comment: @T.C. I see what you mean. Is there anything in the standard where `read` is more restrictive than `write`?